# Why did a 1k resistor at the MOSFET gate solve my problem?

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, motor, mosfet-driver

## Why did a 1k resistor solve my problem?

I wanted to control a 3 wire computer fan with PWM(25 kHz 50% duty) from my Arduino NANO pin 10. My Circuit was very simple. I had an IRLB8721F N-Channel MOSFETn a dell HU843-A00(delta ) Chassis fan, a 4148 flyback diode and a pc power supply which I rigged to output 12v. The Arduino was plugged into my computer's USB.

[image: An image of the circuit should be here...<a href="http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Tutorial/Power_Supplies.html">link</a>...go here bottom of page...with green arrow indicating current flow...this arrow is removed in my post...i also used a mosfet not igbt]

### This is the circuit, except I didn't have the 1k resistor in place.

With out the resistor the fan was squealing and wouldn't run, but with the resistor it was quiet and ran successfully.Why did the resistor solve my problem?

Comment: Is that a BJT there? Or do you really mean a MOSFET?

Comment: I meant MOSFET.

Comment: Probably high frequency oscillation (in the MHz range) due to the stiff gate drive, before. You put in a resistor that damps out the oscillation energy more quickly. My guess.

Comment: You probably created a Pearce oscillator without the resistor. You probably could get away with a 100R

Comment: Remove the 1K and try putting it across Gate and ground and check again if the problem persists.

Comment: Quite possibly you are getting gate "ringing" without the resistor.

Comment: There is inductance everywhere. Whether you used daisy-chain GND, or STAR GND, or GND plane, determine the actual inductances and how they interact with the FET. A FET is ready to oscillate, give some feedback paths.

Answer (score 2):

What may be happening is that your 1k resistor in combination with the gate capacitance is forming a low pass filter. This would cause the fan to experience an oscillating voltage instead of pure pwm. Iirc pc fans have digital controllers that may not play nicely with pwm depending on the frequency. By providing a voltage that never goes to zero, you may be allowing the controller to function continuously instead of resetting over and over again.

Comment: While 4 wire fans expect a steady 12V on the power pin and a 25 kHz PWM signal on the control pin, 3 wire fans typically don't have active circuitry (except for the tach sense), and can be controlled either with DC voltage 0-12V, or a PWMed 12V at a wide range of frequencies.